# Insert a character at a specific position in a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, character

As the title says I want to insert a character after another one in a `char array` using the `C` - style not by using the library `string`, and please avoid using buffer functions as well, only the basic ones :) .

```
char sentence[100],*p = NULL;
cin.get(sentence,100);
char replaceChar; // after What character should we insert
cin>>replaceChar;
char insertingChar; // the character we are inserting after the replaceChar;
cin >> insertingChar ; 
p = strchr(sentence , replace);
while(p != NULL){
//and this is I could think of ...
}
```

So let`s say that we have this sentence : "I want apples", the replaceChar = a, and the insertingChar = '*';

The result should be: "I wa*nt a*pples" .

Comment: Use a `std::string` to make your life easier.

Comment: In your example only 1 of the `a's` is affected, is this by design?

Comment: nope i have a issue while posting this ,the is a * after the first 'a' as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will shift chars to the right, making room for insertion.

```
void rshift( char *s ){
    int n = strlen( s);
    s[ n + 1] = 0;
    while( n ){
       s[ n ] = s[ n-1 ];
       n--;
    } 
}

int main(){

    char *p = strchr(sentence , replace);

    if( p ) {
         p++; // insert after 
         rshift( p );
         *p = insertingChar;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SergeyA, not any more :)

Comment: Assuming, of course, that there is room for all the added characters in the original buffer.  Or *"Use a std::string to make your life easier."*